# SharePoint Server Installation concern

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a machine with the following specifications:

1. 3 GB RAM
2. Core 2 Duo
3. 320 GB HD
4. 32 Bit processor
5. 32 Bit OS

I have Microsoft VS2010 installed on my system.

I am very new to SharePoint and through variuos blogs and forums I have learnt that SharePoint development requires SharePoint Server and SharePoint Server requires the machine to have 64 Bit Windows 7 OS. But, those blogs and forums have old answers(more than 2 years).

Is there a way I can install SharePoint Server 2010 on my machine without having to install a 64 Bit OS. Alternatively, have  there been new releases/versions from MS which support 32 Bit machines ?

Thanks.l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked around for you. I was hoping that maybe you would be able to run a 64-bit VM session on a 32-bit processor but unfortunately you cant. Sorry :(

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way how to run SharePoint 2010 and newer on 32bit OS. :( And also 3GB of RAM is  low.